# How to turn on touchscreen on Samsung ativ book 5

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen, ultrabook

I have a Samsung ativ book 5 laptop that comes with Windows 8 preinstalled.

One of the features that this laptop supports is touch screen. It is disabled by default and I've been searching trough all Windows 8 setting but I just can't find where to turn touch screen on?

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check your device manager for Human interface devices _ should be one there for touch screen...enable it if it has been disabled.